# CSS Suddenly Stopped Working Except For Body Tag

Tags: html, css

My roommate went to turn in his project, and suddenly only the CSS for his body tag still worked (along with the Bootstrap stuff).

If I open up the inspector on the webpage, it doesn't show any of the CSS and if I change any inside the Sublime file it won't show the changes (except for the body tag).

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Siege Strategies</title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/master1.css">

</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="pages/console.html"><i class="fa fa-gamepad" aria-hidden="true"></i> Console</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/pc.html"> <i class="fa fa-laptop" aria-hidden="true"></i> PC</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/audio.html"> <i class="fa fa-headphones" aria-hidden="true"></i> Audio</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Loadout <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="pages/attachments.html"> <i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i> Attachments</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/gadgets.html"> <i class="fa fa-shield" aria-hidden="true"></i> Gadgets</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Strategy <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="pages/teamstrat.html"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> Team Strategy</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/indstrat.html"> <i class="fa fa-street-view" aria-hidden="true"></i> Individual Strategy</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
    <a href="pages/tachanka.html">
      <img src="images/tachanka.png" alt="Chania">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>New Tachanka Spots
        </h3>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <a href="pages/jager.html">
      <img src="images/jager.png" alt="Chania">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Roaming Guide</h3>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <a href="pages/blackbeard.html">
      <img src="images/blackbeard.png" alt="Flower">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Blackbeard Tactics</h3>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <a href="pages/sledge.html">
      <img src="images/sledge.png" alt="Flower">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Sledge Rushing Stats</h3>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    </div>
  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
  </div>

<div class="container">
        <!-- Marketing Icons Section -->
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-6" id="contact">
                <div class="panel panel-default panelsBoy">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Contact Us</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" id="contactus">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://www.twitch.tv"><i class="fa fa-twitch" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://www.reddit.com"><i class="fa fa-reddit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6" id="weekly">
                <div class="panel panel-default panelsBoy">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> Weekly Strategy</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body" id="homebody">
                        <p>Sign up for the weekly strategy newsletter so you can improve your skills!</p>
                        <div class="row" id="button">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
        <a href="pages/form.html"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Sign Up</button></a>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try using an absolute path for `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/master1.css">` ??  Or remove the `.`  ...

Comment: try to put the full path including http.. and Clear your browsing history

Comment: "except for the body tag" what do you mean? do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Does your inspector does not show "file not found" errors?

Comment: There are no "file not found" errors. All paths have been tried. I mean, when I look in the inspector, I can see my CSS for the body tag. Also, if I change the CSS in the body tag, it actually shows up on the page. But none of my other CSS works.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the browser cache and make sure you have correct path mentioned `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master1.css">`